# Is it possible sorting the results in this page [link to the site]/_layouts/15/search.aspx/people?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, modern-experience, people-search

In SharePoint online modern site I created the link in the Quick links web-part with `[link to the site]/_layouts/15/search.aspx/people` which is taking to the People search directly.

Is it possible to sort the results on this page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not supported to sort search results in the Microsoft (modern) search experience.

The feature is only available on classic search result page.

Reference: 
[Search experiences in SharePoint.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/get-started-with-modern-search-experience)